# Codeigniter add url suffix dynamically when search

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

In codeigniter website i have url like this www.mywebsitename.com/used-motorbikes, In that page there is form to search location when user select location EX: location1 then the url should change to something like this 
www.mywebsitename.com/used-motorbikes-location1 is it possible to add like this?

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Add logic in client side js to form this URL first. Then redirect window location to this.

In codeigniter make sure you have route added for www.mywebsitename.com/used-motorbikes-* and handle it to give needed response.

```
$route['used-motorbikes-(:any)']
```